# What's the cause of Nikon FA shutter lag?

Tags: nikon, 35mm

I recently bought a used Nikon FA, and while it works fine without film, it seems to suffer from a shutter "lag" when shooting with film loaded. After pressing the shutter release button, it hangs for a second or two before it fires.

What's going on when this happens? Is this a feature or is my camera broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're not talking about the normal exposure interval delay in *closing* the shutter after opening it, you should never experience any noticable delay in opening the shutter after pressing the shutter button unless:

- Your batteries are low.
- The self timer is slightly engaged.
- There is an electrical fault in the metering system.

The batteries should last 1-3 years for a pair, but I've seen odd behaviour like this with my FA when batteries are very low, so check that first, then play with the self timer.

Now, a few points on FA shutter release behaviour:

- When in M or A exposure modes, the camera uses a *mechanical* shutter retard mechanism. This requires an additional 1-2mm of movement on the shutter release button before it releases the shutter. This is normal and doesn't delay the shutter release as such; it just feels and sounds slightly different.
- When in P or S exposure mode, the FA uses an *electronic* shutter retard mechanism, which is slightly quieter than the mechanical one and the shutter button requires less pressure to release the shutter.

I hope this helps, as the FA is a terrific camera and excels at low light auto exposures.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you. I was referring to opening of the shutter. After pressing the shutter release button in A mode, the shutter speed indicator goes blank for a second or two, before it actually opens the shutter.

Comment: Ok, I just replaced the batteries and checked the self timer, and it's still a noticeable lag of 2-3 seconds from pressing the button till it fires. I guess I might just have gotten a lemon, then. Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: Interesting. Does the same delay happen in P and S modes with the AMP meter engaged? What about with the center-weighted meter engaged? Also as Joanne C rightly pointed out above, the FA has an Off The Film (OTF) reflected light sensor, and behaviour may well differ with/without film loaded. Either way, this delay is very odd and should not be happening. The exact circumstances in which it occurs will likely pinpoint the problem, but it most certainly is electrical in nature.

Comment: Ok, try this: Cock the self-timer fully, then trigger the shutter. When the self timer finishes it's travel, is there a further delay of 2-3 seconds before the shutter actually fires? If so, then this *might* rule out the self timer as being involved. The fact that there is no delay when the shutter is set to M250, but there is a delay with all other modes and shutter speeds(?) suggests this is an electrical fault in the meter, as Bulb and M250 are the only settings where the meter is not engaged.

Comment: The same delay happens in P, S and M, with either AMP or center-weighted meter. I'll try engaging the self-timer check whether there is a delay using the self-timer as well, after I get off work.

Comment: Ok, so I cocked the self-timer fully and triggered the shutter. What happened was that the camera was silently sitting there for a while (approx. 8-10 seconds) before the shutter opened, _then_ I heard the self-timer begin clicking. After a few seconds the shutter closed (it was dark), and then after a few more seconds, the timer stopped clicking. I don't know if this is how it normally works, but maybe you do?

Comment: OK, that's not normal. There should be no perceivable delay between releasing the shutter and hearing the self timer kick in. With the self timer cocked, you should also immediately hear a click when you press the shutter button. This is the mirror popping up, but this is where your camera is not working properly. Here's the confusing part; even though the shutter retard mechanism is mechanical in M and A modes, the shutter *release* is electronic and this is where your problem lies. What I can't yet figure out is why there is a delay instead of just intermittently not working.

Comment: One other important thing to check is to look at the LCD display in the viewfinder when the meter is off (asleep), then lightly press the shutter button in anything except M250 or Bulb mode. You should immediately see something appear on the LCD panel as the meter wakes up. Only press the shutter button once, then wait and see what happens. If there is a delay here then try to figure out if the delay is consistent or random. If nothing happens press the button lightly again then wait some more. If this is just a dirty electrical contact on the shutter release then that's easyish to fix.

Comment: The LCD wakes up immediately, the delay only happens when the shutter release is pressed down enough to trigger a shot. I'm not sure how I will proceed from here, but I might try and disassemble the camera to look for any corrosion in the upcoming future. Hopefully a good cleaning with isopropanol will help, but to be honest I have my doubts. That said, thanks a bounch for your help, you have been most helpful! :)

Comment: No problem, but I must caution you about removing the camera's top plate. The FA is a minefield of electrical wires (not circuit boards - this is a *cybernetic* camera after all) and delicate cable pulleys that transfer setting from the dials to the various mechanisms. Even just getting at the shutter button is tricky. Good luck and take care.

Comment: ...and yeah, I agree that a dirty shutter release seems unlikely here. I'm not very familiar with electronic diagnostics but my money is on a dying capacitor somewhere in the metering/exposure system, as nothing else I can think of would account for a specific delay like this (as it builds it's charge - slower than usual).

Answer (score 3):

The [Nikon FA manual](http://www.nikonpassion.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/manuels/FA_Manual.pdf) is interesting reading... On Page 39 there is a description of the exposure metering system that I think explains the delay you're encountering. Basically, when using one of the automatic modes, the metering system reads the exposure data and compares that to the patterns (about 30,000) stored in memory in order to determine the correct exposure settings when the shutter is released. This can take a bit of time to actually do and then adjust the aperture or shutter speed accordingly.

When you have no film loaded the camera likely detects this and doesn't meter, so no lag.

Comment: Thank you! Wow. I actually read that, but it didn't make sense to me that this should be _slow_ in use.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to override this feature and just go with the set exposure?

Comment: @tiasg - You could shoot fully manual. I'm not especially familiar with that camera, I shot Pentax in my film days, but when shooting manual there should be no need for the camera to make changes to the exposure settings and so it should be faster. I did look around a bit further online and it does seem to be a known behavior of the FA.

Comment: Thank you. Even M mode behaves like this, but the "M 250" mode with a set 1/250 shutter speed do not, so I guess I might be limited to the M 250 if I don't want the shutter lag.